# Ejecución con el condicional de kotlin

Tags: android-studio, variables, kotlin, condiciones

Hola recién me acabo de encontrar con una duda que me ha surgido al ver un tutorial en youtube sobre la condicional sobre kotlin.

```
fun main (){
    var mystring="not empty"
    
    val result= if(mystring ≠ " ") {

      println("not empty")

    }else{

        "empty"
    }
    println(result) }
}
```

Al insertar ciertos valores para ver si mi programa funciona adecuadamente no responde al cambio de número que le pongo y no llega a obedecerme las condicionales que he implementado en mi código.

Por favor soy nuevo programando no me echen de hate la pregunta. :)

Comment: En la pregunta hablas de "cambio de número" pero en el código todo es string. Es el código completo?

Comment: hola @Bicho veras es que en el video que estoy viendo no me aclaro mucho con las condicionales. Si me pudieses pasar algún otro enlace mejor. Aparte de eso en el video aparece como pone las condicionales para que detecten algún cambio sutil en el código y cuando eso ocurra  el {else} actuara para redirgir  ese cambio a unas de las variable y así consigue ejecutar una orden o otra que aparezca en mi código. Ahora en el video el muchacho ponía valores String y Int para ver si el código respondía tanto números como letras. Y si es el código completo :) solo le falta otro valor para activar

Comment: @Bicho condicionales diferentes y darte o una orden u otra. dependiendo de que valores le hayas introducido

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas, no entendí muy bien la parte de "cambio de numero" o sobre cual es tu duda con los condicionales pero te puedo comentar sobre el código:

1. El signo "distinto de" es != en vez de ≠ : `if(mystring != " ")`
2. En el código mostrado el bloque if devuelve "println" (Método para imprimir por consola) que es de tipo Unit, y el else devuelve un string, al ser tipos distintos, "result" es de tipo Any ya que no puede adivinar el resultado:

```
   val result= if(mystring ≠ " ") {
   
     println("not empty")
   
   }else{
   
       "empty"
   }
```

3. El código esta mal indentado, no es obligatorio hacerlo pero si una buena practica y ayuda a ver mejor el código
4. Ten en cuenta que " " no es exactamente vacío ya que contiene un caracter de espacio en blanco, tendría que ser ""
5. Kotlin ofrece extensiones para verificar si un string esta vacío o no:

> .isNotEmpty()
> .isEmpty()

Puedes mirarlo en la documentación:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/

6. La correcion quedaria asi:

```
    fun main (){
        var mystring = "not empty"

        val result = if(mystring.isNotEmpty()) {
            "not empty"
        } else {
            "empty"
        }
        println(result)
    }
```